# Creating user list from 2 info lists

Tags: c#

I have 2 `List`s that contains user infos. The first list contains users `name`, and the second one contains his `age`. I need to create a `List` of type `User` (type `User` has `name` and `age`).

what is the best way to do it?

and what if i have more then 2 lists?

Comment: Please add some samples. It is hard to imagine how those 2 lists look like.

Comment: Could you provide *some examples*? With the desired outcome, please?

Comment: Start writing your first class `User` with  properties `Name` and `Age`(better `DateTime BirthDay`). Then add instances of it to a single `List<User>`

Answer (score 2):

If indexes of lists correspond to same user, try `Zip` lists together:

```
  List<string> names = new List<string>() {
    "John", "Jack", "Me",
  };

  List<int> ages = new List<int>() {
    20, 30, 43,
  };

  // {"John", 20}
  // {"Jack", 30}
  // {"Me", 43}
  List<User> users = names
    .Zip(ages, (name, age) => new User(name, age))
    .ToList();
```

**Edit:** If you have *several lists*, I suggest switching to `Enumerable.Range`:

```
  List<name> names = ...
  List<int> ages = ...
  List<Sex> sexes = ...
  ...

  List<User> users = Enumerable
    .Range(0, new int[] {names.Count, ages.Count, sexes.Count}.Min()) 
    .Select(i => new User(names[i], ages[i], sexes[i]))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks alot! what should i do if iwant to do the same thing but with more then 2 lists ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create list of keyValuePair in C# as below-

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> list3 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        for(int i = 0; i<list1.Count; i++)
        {               
            list3.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(list1[i], list2[i]));         
        }
```